# Is $\frac{dy}{dx}=y(y(x))$ a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question was posted in front of us  by our  professor at IIT-B and said that it was asked by a famous mathematician Arnold.

Comment: It sure is a differential equation.

Comment: Yes, it is a differential equation. Why would it not be? There is no "rigorous" definition of an equation, it's just an equality between two quantities, in this case these two. If it involves the differential operator, then it is a differential equation, simple as that. Yes, if you are asking : "is this a  linear D.E" or "is this a first order differential equation", then maybe that is a better question. I have seen the solution already. (The definition of "equation" is heavily open to interpretation, I request you to define it if it differs from mine).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your definition of a "differential equation".  It does involve $\frac {dy}{dx}$  Usually we do not allow terms like $y(y(x))$ in a differential equation, but anybody asking a question like this should have given you a precise definition which you can apply to the problem at hand.